# How to get value in an object's key using a variable referencing that key?

Tags: javascript

I have an object and I can reference key `a` as in the following:

```js
var obj = {
   a: "A",
   b: "B",
   c: "C"
}

console.log(obj.a); // return string : A
```

I want to get the value by using a variable to reference the object key as below:

```js
var name = "a";
console.log(obj.name) // this prints undefined, but I want it to print "A"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 191):

Use `[]` notation for string representations of properties:

```
console.log(obj[name]);
```

Otherwise it's looking for the "name" property, rather than the "a" property.

Answer (score 27):

`obj["a"]` is equivalent to `obj.a`
so use `obj[name]` you get "**A**"

Comment: Please attention that obj[name] will return obj.name which is undefined.

Comment: Use backticks `` if you're writing short amounts of code

Answer (score 16):

**You can get `value` of `key` like these ways...**

```js
var obj = {
   a: "A",
   b: "B",
   c: "C"
};

console.log(obj.a);

console.log(obj['a']);

name = "a";
console.log(obj[name])
```

Comment: thank you, i personally like the `obj.a` syntax `[+1]`

Answer (score 13):

Use this syntax:

```
obj[name]
```

Note that `obj.x` is the same as `obj["x"]` for all valid JS identifiers, but the latter form accepts all string as keys (not just valid identifiers).

```
obj["Hey, this is ... neat?"] = 42
```

Answer (score 4):

I use the following syntax:

```
objTest = {"error": true, "message": "test message"};
```

get error:

```
 var name = "error"
 console.log(objTest[name]);
```

get message:

```
 name = "message"
 console.log(objTest[name]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
productList = {
        "name": "Title"
}
var key = "name";

console.log(productList[key])
```

`productList` is an arbitraty object with only one key. the `key` variable holds the same key as a string.

Using the `[]` you can access the value dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/sudheernunna/tug98nfm/1/

```
 var days = {};
days["monday"] = true;
days["tuesday"] = true;
days["wednesday"] = false;
days["thursday"] = true;
days["friday"] = false;
days["saturday"] = true;
days["sunday"] = false;
var userfalse=0,usertrue=0;
for(value in days)
{
   if(days[value]){
   usertrue++;
   }else{
   userfalse++;
   }
    console.log(days[value]);
}
alert("false",userfalse);
alert("true",usertrue);
```

Answer (score 2):

fyi, if the type of the object is not known it's a little trickier:

```ts
    var name = "a";
    console.log(obj[name as keyof typeof obj]);
```

(refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38750895/18578004))

Answer (score 1):

```
var o = { cat : "meow", dog : "woof"};
var x = Object.keys(o);

for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
  console.log(o[x[i]]);
}
```

> IAB