# How to get a listing of key value pairs in an object?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [best way to get the key of a key/value javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268679/best-way-to-get-the-key-of-a-key-value-javascript-object)

> foo = {bar: "baz"}

How do you get a listing of all the properties and values within foo?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000953/javascript-object-key-value/47753960#47753960

Answer (score 47, accepted):

A `for in` loop can give you the key and value. Remember to use `const`, `let` or `var` for variable declaration in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

```
for(const p in foo) {
    console.log (p, foo[p])
}
```

From the console:

```
foo = {bar: "baz"}

Object
bar: "baz"
__proto__: Object

for(p in foo) { console.log (p, foo[p]) }
> bar baz
```

If the object you're looping over has has inherited properties from its prototype, you can prevent the inherited properties from being looped over using the `Object.hasOwnProperty()` function like this:

```
for(const p in foo) {
    if (foo.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        console.log (p, foo[p])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through it:

```
for(var i in foo) {
  console.log( i + ": " + foo[i] + "<br />");
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qhLmb/)

Answer (score 1):

This can be different for the different platforms that you are currently working on. If you are running from terminal then you use `print`, if you dont have the `console` object then you can use `document.write()` and so on.

Here is something that you can use/read to understand:

```
var foo = {bar: "baz", boolean: true, num: 2}

for (i in foo) {
//checks to see where to print.
if (typeof console === 'object') 
    console.log(i + ": " + foo[i]);
else if (typeof document === 'object') 
    document.write(i + ": " + foo[i]);
else 
    print(i + ": " + foo[i]);
}
```

Alternatively, if you just say `console.log(foo)` in Chrome/Firefox, the browsers do the looping-highlighting for you and give you a pretty-print of your object, so you dont really need to do the looping shown above.

You can also use `console.debug(foo)` instead of `console.log(foo)`, the difference is subtle. You can read more about this at http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API