# Filter object properties by key in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filter

Let's say I have an object:

```
{
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
}
```

I want to create another object by filtering the object above so I have something like.

```
 {
    item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
    item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
 }
```

I am looking for a clean way to accomplish this using Es6, so spread operators are available to me.

Comment: ES6 has no object spread operators, and you don't need them here anyway

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: filter() for Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072136/javascript-filter-for-objects)

Comment: @DanDascalescu But [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37616104/472610) gives an ES6 way of accomplishing what the OP asks, doesn't it?

Comment: What if I wanted to filter by a key/value?

Answer (score 912, accepted):

If you have a list of allowed values, you can easily retain them in an object using:

```js
const raw = {
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
};

const allowed = ['item1', 'item3'];

const filtered = Object.keys(raw)
  .filter(key => allowed.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = raw[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});

console.log(filtered);
```

This uses:

1. [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to list all properties in `raw` (the original data), then
2. [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to select keys that are present in the allowed list, using

   1. [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to make sure they are present
3. [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build a new object with only the allowed properties.

This will make a shallow copy with the allowed properties (but won't copy the properties themselves).

You can also use [the object spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to create a series of objects without mutating them (thanks to [rjerue for mentioning this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6/38750895?noredirect=1#comment84340622_38750895)):

```js
const raw = {
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
};

const allowed = ['item1', 'item3'];

const filtered = Object.keys(raw)
  .filter(key => allowed.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    return {
      ...obj,
      [key]: raw[key]
    };
  }, {});

console.log(filtered);
```

For purposes of trivia, if you wanted to remove the unwanted fields from the original data (which I **would not** recommend doing, since it involves some ugly mutations), you could invert the `includes` check like so:

```js
const raw = {
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
};

const allowed = ['item1', 'item3'];

Object.keys(raw)
  .filter(key => !allowed.includes(key))
  .forEach(key => delete raw[key]);

console.log(raw);
```

I'm including this example to show a mutation-based solution, but I don't suggest using it.

Comment: Thanks that worked great. I also found an approach by using 'deconstruction syntax.                                                                           IE :                                                                                                      const {item1,item3} = raw
const newObject = {item1,item3}

Comment: Deconstruction will work (just fine), but is purely compile-time. You can't make it a dynamic list of properties or provide any complex rules (a loop can have validation callbacks attached, for example).

Comment: yep exactly. your way is obviously the better approach for anything dynamic, thanks again

Comment: I can't vote this up enough! Well done for using filter and reduce and not constructing another object from a for loop. And awesome that you explicitly separated the immutable and mutable versions. +1

Comment: Quick warning: `Array.prototype.includes` is not part of ES6. It's introduced in ECMAScript 2016 (ES7).

Comment: If you want to do the reduce in an immutable way, you could also replace the function contents with 

    return { ...obj, [key]: raw[key] }

Comment: @rjerue that's a good point. I'll update the answer to include object spread, unless you'd rather suggest it for the rep. :)

Comment: Using a `filter` before the `reduce` slows down the operation. Instead, you can use a conditional within the `reduce`. This is ~50% faster.

Comment: This is simply brilliant and clean code. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries (less support)` would work like a charm too, also if worries about mutation could try `Object.clone`

Comment: This solution helped me to fix a problem of mine. Even the it required a different approach but thanks a lot.

Comment: I would consider using a Set instead of Array for allowed keys and set will have average O(n) but for array on each cycle iteration we will have to look through array which may give us O(n+m) where m is length of allowed keys

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something, but isn't calling reduce redundant since filter creates a shallow copy?

Answer (score 186):

If you are OK with using ES6 syntax, I find that the cleanest way to do this, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34710102/305383) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40699547/305383) is:

```
const data = {
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
};

const { item2, ...newData } = data;
```

Now, `newData` contains:

```
{
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
};
```

Or, if you have the key stored as a string:

```
const key = 'item2';
const { [key]: _, ...newData } = data;
```

In the latter case, `[key]` is converted to `item2` but since you are using a `const` assignment, you need to specify a name for the assignment. `_` represents a throw away value.

More generally:

```
const { item2, ...newData } = data; // Assign item2 to item2
const { item2: someVarName, ...newData } = data; // Assign item2 to someVarName
const { item2: _, ...newData } = data; // Assign item2 to _
const { ['item2']: _, ...newData } = data; // Convert string to key first, ...
```

Not only does this reduce your operation to a one-liner but it also doesn't require you to know what the other keys are (those that you want to preserve).

A simple utility function would look like this:

```
function removePropFromObject(obj, prop) {
  const { [prop]: _, ...rest } = obj
  return { ...rest }
}
```

Comment: " `_` represents a throw away value" where does this come? First time I see it

Comment: I believe this is an adopted convention by the JS community. An `_` is simply a valid variable name that can be used in JS but since it is pretty much nameless, it really shouldn't be used in that way if you care to convey intent. So, it's been adopted as a way to denote a variable you don't care about. Here's further discussion about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406823/underscore-as-a-javascript-variable

Comment: This is much tidier than the accepted answer, avoids the overhead of creating a new array with Object.keys(), and the overhead of iterating the array with `filter` and `reduce`.

Comment: @yhabib the `_` doesn't matter, it's just a variable name, you can rename it to anything you want

Comment: In the `removePropFromObject` function, is there any need to return the value spreaded again? I.e. couldn't you just do `return rest` instead of `return { ...rest }`?

Comment: I love the simplicity of spread operations and I'm trying to understand it more. Is it possible to use this same solution if instead of a singular key like 'item2' you have an array of non-permitted keys `['item2', 'item4']`? And even more so, what if it was an array of non-permitted values  like `'[sdfd', 'abcd']` in 
`{
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'abcd' }
};`

Answer (score 83):

You can now make it shorter and simpler by using the ***Object.fromEntries*** method (check browser support):

```
const raw = { item1: { prop:'1' }, item2: { prop:'2' }, item3: { prop:'3' } };

const allowed = ['item1', 'item3'];

const filtered = Object.fromEntries(
   Object.entries(raw).filter(
      ([key, val])=>allowed.includes(key)
   )
);
```

read more about: [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Comment: This is now the best way I think. Much more intuitive than reduce.

Comment: For the record. When using `Object.fromEntries` with `Typescript` make sure that `"lib": ["ES2019"]` is set in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: I like the `entries/fromEntries` trick but if it's a big object, it might hurt performance - https://jsbench.me/3ukxxhfgjr/1

Comment: I'm interested in how this cases are handled by JS Engine (V8 for example)?

In my understanding of inline caches example with loop will give us a megamorphic object and approach with object from entries should construct object with single shape

Comment: Here a type-safe (TypeScript) version of the code in the answer: `const excludeKeysFromObject = <T extends {}>(obj: T, allowedKeys: (keyof T)[]) =>
  Object.fromEntries((Object.keys(obj) as (keyof T)[]).filter(key => allowedKeys.includes(key)).map(key => [key, obj[key]]))`

Answer (score 72):

Nothing that hasn't been said before, but to combine some answers to a general ES6 answer:

```js
const raw = {
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value: 'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value: 'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value: 'sdfd' }
};

const filteredKeys = ['item1', 'item3'];

const filtered = filteredKeys
  .reduce((obj, key) => ({ ...obj, [key]: raw[key] }), {});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: this is a much more simple and performant solution than others ;)

Comment: Good succinct solution. Note that if there's a key in `filteredKeys` that's not in `raw`, that key will show up in `filtered` with a value of `undefined`. In other answers, that key won't show up in `filtered` at all.

Answer (score 65):

The cleanest way you can find is with [Lodash#pick](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick)

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const allowed = ['item1', 'item3'];

const obj = {
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
}

const filteredObj = _.pick(obj, allowed)
```

Comment: It's important to point out that for it an extra project dependency has to be downloaded on runtime.

Comment: _.omit(obj, ["item2"]) - lodash.omit is an opposite to lodash.pick

Comment: There's also ramda.pick if you use Ramda! https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pick

Answer (score 35):

Just another solution in **one line of Modern JS with no external libraries**.

I was playing with "**Destructuring**" feature :

```js
const raw = {
    item1: { key: 'sdfd', value: 'sdfd' },
    item2: { key: 'sdfd', value: 'sdfd' },
    item3: { key: 'sdfd', value: 'sdfd' }
  };
var myNewRaw = (({ item1, item3}) => ({ item1, item3 }))(raw);
console.log(myNewRaw);
```

Comment: `var myNewRaw = (({ item1, item3}) => ({ item1, item3 }))(raw);`
Syntax issue

Comment: There are a couple of things condensed here: First thing first, there is the declaration of the function. it is an arrow function (it takes an object and return an object) . It is the same thing as function(obj){return obj;}. the second thing is that ES6 allow destructuring future. In my function declaration I destructure my object{ item1, item3}. And the last thing is that I self invoke my function. You can use self invoke function to manage your scope for example. But here it was just to condense the code. I hope it is clear. If I miss something feel free to add more.

Comment: this is the preferred modern approach imho

Comment: I believe this will add keys that are missing in the original object.

Comment: What do  you mean @AjahnCharles? Could you help me get your point please?

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38750895/2957169) will only include keys that are in the filter list AND exist in the original data. I believe your answer will insert missing keys with `undefined` as the value, for example if my original data didn't include `item3`, I think your code would add it. There might be use-cases where that's undesirable. (for my use-case it's fine! I'm using it!)

Comment: @Novy Thanks for this amazing answer. I've learned about self-invoking functions and destructuring today and thanks for that. There is 1 thing I do not understand why is the body of the arrow function wrapped in parentheses? this part after the arrow: ` => ({ item1, item3})`. I understand that parenthesis left of the arrow hold function parameters but I expected simple function { body } on the right side. Why do we need them or what are they called? I can't google them (they don't seem like the normal Grouping Paramemeter)

Comment: @NikaKasradze without those parentheses the function will return undefined. Awol did help me  with that point at the first time. And after reading blogs and read the specification I understand it better. It will try a brief explanation in another comment if you do not mind.

Comment: @NikaKasradze According to specification [Arrow Function syntax](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions) is:
ArrowParameters => ConciseBody
and the  ConciseBody : { FunctionBody }
In our case With simply the brackets after the arrow the parser will see it as your conciseBody. 
>>>> next part coming

Comment: @NikaKasradze ... You also know if your arrow function is a one line expression you do not need to put explicitly the return keyword and you can drop the brackets . You have something like 
ArrowParameters => returnValue. If the return value is an object literal you have to force it as an an expression and the way to do it is to add these parentheses. I hope it is clearer for you. Sorry for my english by the way.

Comment: same as: `function filterObject(object){ let {item1, item3} = object; return {item1, item3};   filterObject(/* your object */)`

Comment: It is a good practice to use named function. It better in the stack trace when you are debugging. IFFIEs are good for one time thing that you do not want to reuse somewhereelse.You can even do something like this : function filterObject({item1, item3}){ return {item1, item3};} And then call  filterObject(/* your object */) as you said

Answer (score 32):

Building on these two answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56081419/13819049
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54976713/13819049

We can do:

```js
const original = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const allowed = ['a', 'b'];

const filtered = Object.fromEntries(allowed.map(k => [k, original[k]]));
```

Which is cleaner and faster:

https://jsbench.me/swkv2cbgkd/1

Comment: Beauty one-liner; just what I needed, thx.

Comment: Holy smokes, I have no idea what this is doing but it sure saved me!

Comment: It goes through each item in allowed, and converts it to a tuple (fancy way of saying array) of two things - the first being the item, the second being the value of 'original'. Then we have an array of 'entries' [['a', 1], ['b', 2]] and they get converted into an object

Answer (score 23):

ok, how about this one-liner

```
    const raw = {
      item1: { key: 'sdfd', value: 'sdfd' },
      item2: { key: 'sdfd', value: 'sdfd' },
      item3: { key: 'sdfd', value: 'sdfd' }
    };

    const filteredKeys = ['item1', 'item3'];

    const filtered = Object.assign({}, ...filteredKeys.map(key=> ({[key]:raw[key]})));
```

Comment: what if you only know the keys you want to remove...not that keys you want to keep?

Answer (score 19):

Another solution using the [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method on the allowed keys:

```
const raw = {
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
};

const allowed = ['item1', 'item3'];

const filtered = allowed.reduce((obj, key) => { 
  obj[key] = raw[key]; 
  return obj 
}, {})

console.log(filtered);
```

Especially in case of larger source objects (raw in this example) it would make sense. The iteration will not be executed using all the entries of the source, but only using the keys you want to filter, thus shorter/faster...

[Demonstration in **this Fiddle**...](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/ebk278tp/)

---

But I do have to say I also like the solution in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56081419/5522000) which is using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

> ```
> const object = Object.fromEntries(
>   Object.entries(raw).filter(([key, value]) => allowed.includes(key))
> );
> ```

[Demonstration in **this Fiddle**...](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/zoj50fa8/)

Comment: Wilt, your second approach is an exact duplicate of this answer provided last year: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56081419/5522000

Comment: @ArtSchmidt Thank you for your comment: Missed that one in the long list. I will refer to that answer instead.

Comment: What is "new" about `.reduce()`? I suppose this comment comes from the future but I don't think it was new in 2020, either.

Comment: @VLAZ, not sure why I wrote that at the time, maybe because some people even today still want to support IE8 and it won't work there. I removed the "new" from the answer...

Answer (score 13):

You can add a generic `ofilter` (implemented with generic `oreduce`) so you can easily filter objects the same way you can arrays –

```
const oreduce = (f, acc, o) =>
  Object
    .entries (o)
    .reduce
      ( (acc, [ k, v ]) => f (acc, v, k, o)
      , acc
      )

const ofilter = (f, o) =>
  oreduce
    ( (acc, v, k, o)=>
        f (v, k, o)
          ? Object.assign (acc, {[k]: v})
          : acc
    , {}
    , o
    )
```

We can see it working here -

```
const data =
  { item1: { key: 'a', value: 1 }
  , item2: { key: 'b', value: 2 }
  , item3: { key: 'c', value: 3 }
  }

console.log
  ( ofilter
      ( (v, k) => k !== 'item2'
      , data
      )
      // [ { item1: { key: 'a', value: 1 } }
      // , { item3: { key: 'c', value: 3 } }
      // ]

  , ofilter
      ( x => x.value === 3
      , data
      )
      // [ { item3: { key: 'c', value: 3 } } ]
  )
```

Verify the results in your own browser below –

```js
const oreduce = (f, acc, o) =>
  Object
    .entries (o)
    .reduce
      ( (acc, [ k, v ]) => f (acc, v, k, o)
      , acc
      )

const ofilter = (f, o) =>
  oreduce
    ( (acc, v, k, o)=>
        f (v, k, o)
          ? Object.assign (acc, { [k]: v })
          : acc
    , {}
    , o
    )

const data =
  { item1: { key: 'a', value: 1 }
  , item2: { key: 'b', value: 2 }
  , item3: { key: 'c', value: 3 }
  }

console.log
  ( ofilter
      ( (v, k) => k !== 'item2'
      , data
      )
      // [ { item1: { key: 'a', value: 1 } }
      // , { item3: { key: 'c', value: 3 } }
      // ]

  , ofilter
      ( x => x.value === 3
      , data
      )
      // [ { item3: { key: 'c', value: 3 } } ]
  )
```

These two functions could be implemented in many ways. I chose to attach to `Array.prototype.reduce` inside `oreduce` but you could just as easily write it all from scratch

Comment: I like your solution, but I don't know how much clearer / more efficient it is compared to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37616104/472610).

Comment: Here is a [benchmark](https://jsperf.com/ed-3-vs-es-2015-vs-es-2016/1) showing that your solution is the fastest.

Comment: In `oreduce`, the first `acc` is shadowed in `.reduce(acc, k)`, and in `ofilter` the `o` is shadowed - `oreduce` is called with a variable called `o` as well - which is which?

Comment: in `ofilter` the variable `o` is shadowed but it always points to the the same input var; that’s why its shadowed here, *because* it’s the same - the accumulator (`acc`) is also shadowed because it more clearly shows how the data moves thru the lambda; `acc` is not always the same *binding*, but it always represents the current *persistent* state of the computational result we wish to return

Comment: While the code works well and the method is very good I do wonder what help writing code like that is to somebody obviously needing help with javascript. I'm all for brevity but that is almost as compact as a minimized code.

Answer (score 10):

The answers here are definitely suitable but they are a bit slow because they require looping through the whitelist for every property in the object. The solution below is much quicker for large datasets because it only loops through the whitelist once:

```js
const data = {
  allowed1: 'blah',
  allowed2: 'blah blah',
  notAllowed: 'woah',
  superSensitiveInfo: 'whooooah',
  allowed3: 'bleh'
};

const whitelist = ['allowed1', 'allowed2', 'allowed3'];

function sanitize(data, whitelist) {
  return whitelist.reduce(
    (result, key) =>
      data[key] !== undefined
        ? Object.assign(result, { [key]: data[key] })
        : result,
    {}
  );
}

const result = sanitize(data, whitelist);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 9):

This is how I did it, recently:

```
const dummyObj = Object.assign({}, obj);
delete dummyObj[key];
const target = Object.assign({}, {...dummyObj});
```

Comment: Hm. It seems you're mixing old and new syntax. `Object.assign == ...` You could write `const dummyObj = { ...obj }` and `const target = { ...dummyObj }`. Plus, the latter is not at all necessary, since you could directly work with dummyObj afterwards.

Comment: This does *three* copies of an object. Just to only get one of those with the key removed: `dummyObj = Object.assign({}, obj)` - clone `obj` into a new object called `dummyObj`; `delete dummyObj[key];` - remove the key. At this point *your job is done*. But then: `{...dummyObj}` - clone `dummyObj` (which is already a clone) into a temporary object; ` target = Object.assign({}, {...dummyObj})` - clone the cloned temporary object (a clone of a clone) into a new object called `target`.

Answer (score 8):

A simpler solution without using `filter` can be achieved with `Object.entries()` instead of `Object.keys()`

```
const raw = {
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
};

const allowed = ['item1', 'item3'];

const filtered = Object.entries(raw).reduce((acc,elm)=>{
  const [k,v] = elm
  if (allowed.includes(k)) {
    acc[k] = v 
  }
  return acc
},{})
```

Answer (score 7):

Piggybacking on [ssube's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38750895/290340).

Here's a reusable version.

```
Object.filterByKey = function (obj, predicate) {
  return Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(key => predicate(key))
    .reduce((out, key) => {
      out[key] = obj[key];
      return out;
    }, {});
}
```

To call it use

```
const raw = {
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
};

const allowed = ['item1', 'item3'];

var filtered = Object.filterByKey(raw, key => 
  return allowed.includes(key));
});

console.log(filtered);
```

The beautiful thing about ES6 arrow functions is that you don't have to pass in `allowed` as a parameter.

Answer (score 6):

**Simple Way! To do this.**

```js
const myData = {
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
};
const{item1,item3}=myData
const result =({item1,item3})
```

Comment: You are not actually filtering anything here, just destructuring the data given. But what happens when the data changes?

Comment: @IdrisDopicoPeña - The destructuring is the filter. How is an object of fieldnames any different to using an array of field names? (though this solution will add missing keys)

Comment: @charles-allen an array of field names can be changed more easily without requiring the code that uses it to change. So you can have a reusable function that takes that array and filters your object, e.g., `myFunc(["item1", "item3"])` can later be reused as `myFunc(["foo", "bar"])` without changing anything about how it works. With this approach you need different function for each object you want to filter the keys of.

Comment: @VLAZ - True. Maybe I misunderstood Idris. I thought they meant different `myData`, not a different filter (that is my use case -- I know what properties I need at compile time, so this solution is much sleaker).

Comment: @charles-allen I'm not saying this solution is wrong. It's indeed very useful. However, the question was what's the difference. If I needed to extract `item1` and `item3` one time and then `foo` and `bar` another time, I'd probably just go with destructuring twice. If I need to do it a lot more often than that or I don't even know which ones I want, then I'd go with a function.

Comment: @VLAZ - Completely agree with you!

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
const base = {
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
};

const filtered = (
    source => { 
        with(source){ 
            return {item1, item3} 
        } 
    }
)(base);

// one line
const filtered = (source => { with(source){ return {item1, item3} } })(base);
```

This works but is not very clear, plus the `with` statement is not recommended (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

Comment: This...is horrible. I'm aware `with` has its (very, very few) uses but this isn't one of them. It's just destructuring with extra steps. `source => { with(source){ return {item1, item3} } }` is equivalent to `({item1, item3}) => ({item1, item3})` [which is already an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49340650/).

Answer (score 5):

I know that this already has plenty of answers *and* is a rather old question. But I just came up with this neat one-liner:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(raw, ['key', 'value', 'item1', 'item3']))
```

That returns another object with just the whitelisted attributes. Note that the `key` and `value` is included in the list.

Comment: Love this! Probably really quick execution, and it's easy to filter out one or more properties

Comment: @JanisJansen serialising and de-serialising an object doesn't seem very quick to me. Also, you'd lose values like functions, or `undefined`, or `NaN` or BigInts.

Answer (score 4):

```
const filteredObject = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(originalObject).filter(([key, value]) => key !== uuid))
```

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer, please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to accomplish this. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38750895/3966682) uses a Keys-Filter-Reduce approach, which is not the most performant.

Instead, using a `for...in` loop to loop through keys of an object, or looping through the allowed keys, and *then* composing a new object is ~50% more performant<sup>a</sup>.

```
const obj = {
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
};

const keys = ['item1', 'item3'];

function keysReduce (obj, keys) {
  return keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    if(obj[key] !== undefined) {
      acc[key] = obj[key];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
};

function forInCompose (obj, keys) {
  const returnObj = {};
  for (const key in obj) {
    if(keys.includes(key)) {
      returnObj[key] = obj[key]
    }
  };
  return returnObj;
};

keysReduce(obj, keys);   // Faster if the list of allowed keys are short
forInCompose(obj, keys); // Faster if the number of object properties are low
```

---

<sup>a. See [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/filter-object-by-key-standard/1) for the benchmarks of a simple use case. Results will differ based on browsers.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can remove a spesific property on your object

```
items={
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
}

// Example 1
var key = "item2";
delete items[key]; 

// Example 2
delete items["item2"];

// Example 3
delete items.item2;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Another short way**

```js
function filterByKey(v,keys){
  const newObj ={};
  keys.forEach(key=>{v[key]?newObj[key]=v[key]:''});
  return newObj;
}

//given
let obj ={ foo: "bar", baz: 42,baz2:"blabla" , "spider":"man", monkey:true};

//when
let outObj =filterByKey(obj,["bar","baz2","monkey"]);

//then 
console.log(outObj);
  //{
  //  "baz2": "blabla",
  //  "monkey": true
  //}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following method takes the object and any properties to filter out.

```js
function removeObjectKeys(obj, ...keysToRemove) {
  let mObject = { ...obj }
  for (let key of keysToRemove) {
    const { [String(key)]: _, ...rest } = mObject
    mObject = { ...rest }
  }
  return mObject
}
    
const obj = { 123: "hello", 345: "world", 567: "and kitty" };
const filtered = removeObjectKeys(obj, 123);
console.log(filtered);

const twoFiltered = removeObjectKeys(obj, 345, 567);
console.log(twoFiltered);
```

Comment: this gives a linting error as the `_`  is not used anywhere else, but it's very creative none the less.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the above solutions repeatedly call `Array.prototype.includes` for each key in `raw`, which will make the solution O(n·m) (where n is the number of keys in the object an m is the length of the allowed list).

This could be avoided by using an allowed Set, but iterating over the `allowed` keys and copying them to an initially-empty object gives very simple, readable code that is O(m):

```js
const raw = {
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
};

const allowed = ['item1', 'item3'];

const filtered = {};
for (const key of allowed) {
  if (key in raw) filtered[key] = raw[key];
}

console.log(filtered);
```

You could also use `raw.hasOwnProperty(key)` instead of `key in raw` if you wanted to avoid copying inherited properties.

Answer (score 1):

**OK,** how about this:

```
const myData = {
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
};

function filteredObject(obj, filter) {
  if(!Array.isArray(filter)) {
   filter = [filter.toString()];
  }
  const newObj = {};
  for(i in obj) {
    if(!filter.includes(i)) {
      newObj[i] = obj[i];
    }
  }
  return newObj;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
filteredObject(myData, ['item2']); //{item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }, item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will filter an object based on a list of keys, its more efficient than the previous answer as it doesn't have to use Array.filter before calling reduce. so its O(n) as opposed to O(n + filtered)

```
function filterObjectByKeys (object, keys) {
  return Object.keys(object).reduce((accum, key) => {
    if (keys.includes(key)) {
      return { ...accum, [key]: object[key] }
    } else {
      return accum
    }
  }, {})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised how nobody has suggested this yet. It's super clean and very explicit about which keys you want to keep.

```
const unfilteredObj = {a: ..., b:..., c:..., x:..., y:...}

const filterObject = ({a,b,c}) => ({a,b,c})
const filteredObject = filterObject(unfilteredObject)
```

Or if you want a dirty one liner:

```
const unfilteredObj = {a: ..., b:..., c:..., x:..., y:...}

const filteredObject = (({a,b,c})=>({a,b,c}))(unfilteredObject);
```

Comment: This method will add a key not present in the original array.
Might be a problem or not, this should be at least pointed out.

Comment: I think this guy suggested it already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49340650/2957169

Comment: "*I'm surprised how nobody has suggested this yet.*" it's already been suggested [by Novy in November 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49340650/) and [by ghanshyam bendkoli in December 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59535105/).

Answer (score 0):

During loop, return nothing when certain properties/keys are encountered and continue with the rest:

```
const loop = product =>
Object.keys(product).map(key => {
    if (key === "_id" || key === "__v") {
        return; 
    }
    return (
        <ul className="list-group">
            <li>
                {product[key]}
                <span>
                    {key}
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `Array.prototype.forEach()` as

```js
const raw = {
  item1: {
    key: 'sdfd',
    value: 'sdfd'
  },
  item2: {
    key: 'sdfd',
    value: 'sdfd'
  },
  item3: {
    key: 'sdfd',
    value: 'sdfd'
  }
};

const allowed = ['item1', 'item3', 'lll'];

var finalObj = {};
allowed.forEach(allowedVal => {
  if (raw[allowedVal])
    finalObj[allowedVal] = raw[allowedVal]
})
console.log(finalObj)
```

It includes values of only those keys which are available in the raw data and thus preventing adding any junk data.

Answer (score 0):

That would be my solution:

```
const filterObject = (obj, condition) => {
    const filteredObj = {};
    Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
      if (condition(key)) {
        dataFiltered[key] = obj[key];
      }
    });
  return filteredObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [PropPick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-pick) package

```js
pick('item1 item3', obj);
// {
//   item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
//   item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to dump this code somewhere for the record. The code uses proxies to implement

1. an object with a frozen set of keys and
2. a template object that produces a derived object that has only such keys of the template that have been subsequently assigned a value.

---

```
const unlock = Symbol("unlock");
const lock = (o) =>
  new Proxy(o, {
    get: (target, property) =>
      property === unlock ? target : Reflect.get(target, property),
    set: (target, key, value) =>
      o.hasOwnProperty(key) ? Reflect.set(target, key, value) : true,
  });

const obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const obj2 = { b: 3, c: 4 };
const result = Object.assign(lock(obj1), obj2)[unlock];

console.log(result); // { a: 1, b: 3 }
console.log(result === obj1); // true



const derived = Symbol("derived");
const template = (o) =>
  new Proxy(Object.create(null), {
    get: (target, property) =>
      property === derived ? target : Reflect.get(target, property),
    set: (target, key, value) =>
      o.hasOwnProperty(key) ? Reflect.set(target, key, value) : true,
  });

const obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const obj2 = { b: 3, c: 4 };
const result = Object.assign(template(obj1), obj2)[derived];

console.log(result); // { b: 3 }
```