# How to filter object by check the key

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have array objects, and I want to remove some inner objects if the key is not match.

Input:

```
"configuration" : {
    "11111-2222-3333-444--5555" : {
        "home1" : 
             {
               "tel" : "125", 
               "address" : true, 
             }
    }, 
    "2222-3333-44444-5555--66666" : {
        "home2" : 
             {
               "tel" : "125", 
               "address" : true, 
             }
    }
}
```

I have a match string `11111-2222-3333-444--5555`

The expected out:

```
"configuration" : {
    "11111-2222-3333-444--5555" : {
        "home1" : 
             {
               "tel" : "125", 
               "address" : true
             }
         }

   }
```

Comment: It is not an array of objects. It is just a object with multiple keys.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/using-es6-to-filter-object-properties

Comment: So for one specific key? You could do `{'configuration': {'11111-2222-3333-444--5555': original['configuration']['11111-2222-3333-444--5555']}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_.pick()` to get the key you want:

```js
var data = {"configuration":{"11111-2222-3333-444--5555":{"home1":{"tel":"125","address":true}},"2222-3333-44444-5555--66666":{"home2":{"tel":"125","address":true}}}};

var searchKey = '11111-2222-3333-444--5555';

var result = {
  configuration: _.pick(data.configuration, searchKey)
};

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @thomas: if you found this answer useful, please accept it by clicking on the grey ✓.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the keys and delete the ones you don't want:

```
let o = {
  configuration: { /* etc. */ }
}

for(let key in o.configuration) {
  if(key !== '11111-2222-3333-444--5555') {
    delete o[key]
  }
}
```

However this is unnecessary if you're removing all but just one key. To simplify it, you could do:

```
let newObject = {
  configuration: {
    '11111-2222-3333-444--5555': o.configuration['11111-2222-3333-444--5555']
  }
}
```