# Filter object properties by key, but keep filtered keys from whitelist as empty

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need some help to filter object properties by key, but keep filtered keys from whitelist as empty.

I am using the function from this answer on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38750895/5397658

Preview:

```js
const raw = {
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
};

const allowed = ['item1', 'item3'];

const filtered = Object.keys(raw)
  .filter(key => allowed.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = raw[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});

console.log(filtered);
```

In my scenario, I have this as a whitelist:

```
var whitelist = ["ApartmentNumber", "FloorSpace", "PrimaryRoomSpace", "CaseStatusType", "AskingPrice"];
```

And this is the raw object:

```
{
    "Id": 668,
    "ProjectId": 667,
    "NumberOfBedrooms": 2,
    "FloorSpace": 60,
    "PrimaryRoomSpace": 60,
    "LandLotType": "None",
    "ApartmentNumber": "L-101\r",
    "PublicationTitle": "L-101",
    "PublicationInformationId": 49,
    "CaseStatusId": 227,
    "CaseStatusType": "Ready",
    "CaseStatusName": "Salgsklar",
    "CaseReferralKey": "80-17-10001",
    "AskingPrice": 10000000,
    "EnergyLabel": "None",
    "HeatingGrade": "None",
    "Comission": 0,
    "DocumentCostBasis": 10000000,
    "PricePerSquareMeter": 166666.66666666666666666667,
    "Street": "Street 1",
    "ZipCode": "0682",
    "BuyerIds": [],
    "ResponsibleBrokerId": 0,
    "BrokerId": 0
},
{
    "Id": 669,
    "ProjectId": 667,
    "NumberOfBedrooms": 2,
    "NumberOfBedroomsMax": 2,
    "FloorSpace": 0,
    "FloorSpaceMax": 100,
    "PrimaryRoomSpace": 90,
    "PrimaryRoomSpaceMax": 90,
    "ApartmentNumber": "L-107\r",
    "CaseStatusId": 207,
    "CaseStatusType": "Active",
    "CaseStatusName": "Oppdrag akseptert",
    "CaseReferralKey": "80-17-10007",
    "StoreyOf": 1,
    "EnergyLabel": "None",
    "HeatingGrade": "None",
    "Comission": 0,
    "DocumentCostBasis": 0,
    "Street": "Street 2",
    "ZipCode": "0682",
    "BuyerIds": [],
    "ResponsibleBrokerId": 0,
    "BrokerId": 0
},
{
    "Id": 670,
    "ProjectId": 667,
    "NumberOfBedrooms": 2,
    "NumberOfBedroomsMax": 2,
    "FloorSpace": 0,
    "FloorSpaceMax": 100,
    "PrimaryRoomSpace": 90,
    "PrimaryRoomSpaceMax": 90,
    "ApartmentNumber": "L-106\r",
    "CaseStatusId": 223,
    "CaseStatusType": "General",
    "CaseStatusName": "Bestilt info",
    "CaseReferralKey": "80-17-10006",
    "StoreyOf": 1,
    "EnergyLabel": "None",
    "HeatingGrade": "None",
    "Comission": 0,
    "DocumentCostBasis": 0,
    "Street": "Street 1",
    "ZipCode": "0682",
    "BuyerIds": [],
    "ResponsibleBrokerId": 0,
    "BrokerId": 0
},
{
    "Id": 671,
    "ProjectId": 667,
    "NumberOfBedroomsMax": 1,
    "FloorSpace": 0,
    "FloorSpaceMax": 50,
    "ApartmentNumber": "L-102\r",
    "CaseStatusId": 219,
    "CaseStatusType": "General",
    "CaseStatusName": "All info mottatt",
    "CaseReferralKey": "80-17-10002",
    "StoreyOf": 2,
    "EnergyLabel": "None",
    "HeatingGrade": "None",
    "Comission": 0,
    "DocumentCostBasis": 0,
    "PricePerSquareMeter": 0,
    "Street": "Street 1",
    "ZipCode": "0682",
    "BuyerIds": [],
    "ResponsibleBrokerId": 0,
    "BrokerId": 0
}
```

This is the output from the filter function for the first object, which is works for me because it has all the values from the whitelist present:

```
{ ApartmentNumber: 'L-101\r',
  FloorSpace: 60,
  PrimaryRoomSpace: 60,
  CaseStatusType: 'Ready',
  AskingPrice: 10000000 }
```

But for the second object, it will look like this. It is missing the AskingPrice, since its not present in the second object:

```
{ ApartmentNumber: 'L-107\r',
  FloorSpace: 0,
  PrimaryRoomSpace: 90,
  CaseStatusType: 'Active' }
```

The problem is that I need the filtered keys which is present in the whitelist, they can't be removed. I want them to be empty instead, if not present in the raw object.

To clarify, I need the second object to look like this instead:

```
{ ApartmentNumber: 'L-107\r',
  FloorSpace: 0,
  PrimaryRoomSpace: 90,
  CaseStatusType: 'Active',
  AskingPrice: ''} //<-- empty string
```

How can the filter function be adjusted to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need all of your allowed keys in your `filtered` object, you can loop over the `allowed` array and check if the `whitelist key` is present in your `raw object` and simply add the key if not present with `null` or desired value. Sample code is below.

```js
const raw = {
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
};

const allowed = ['item1', 'item3'];

let filtered = {}

allowed.forEach( key => {
  filtered[key] = (typeof raw[key] === 'undefined') ? '' : raw[key];
})

console.log(filtered);
```

As pointed out by @GrégoryNEUT, please notice the condition we are using, it will not remove the keys which will have values like `null`, `false` or `0`. If you want to remove all these types of values also, please use the under given condition.

```
filtered[key] = raw[key] ? {} : raw[key];
```

Comment: Please use `typeof raw[key] === 'undefined'`. using `raw[key] === undefined` compare `raw[key]` to the variable `undefined` which is `undefined` because it don't exist. Do `const undefined = 50;` before and it doesn't work anymore. Plus `filtered` is a `const`.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT, thanks for pointing that out. Made the changes in the answer

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT Well there's no need to write `raw[key] === 'undefined'` either, you can simply use `raw[key]` as a condition, if it's undefined the condition won't be fulfilled.

Comment: @chsdk yeah but if `raw[key] = false` or `raw[key] = 0` you gonna have some problem

Comment: @veb, please accept the answer if it answers your question else, please explain your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick. Use `Array.prototype.reduce`.

```js
const raw = [{
    "Id": 668,
    "ProjectId": 667,
    "NumberOfBedrooms": 2,
    "FloorSpace": 60,
    "PrimaryRoomSpace": 60,
    "LandLotType": "None",
    "ApartmentNumber": "L-101\r",
    "PublicationTitle": "L-101",
    "PublicationInformationId": 49,
    "CaseStatusId": 227,
    "CaseStatusType": "Ready",
    "CaseStatusName": "Salgsklar",
    "CaseReferralKey": "80-17-10001",
    "AskingPrice": 10000000,
    "EnergyLabel": "None",
    "HeatingGrade": "None",
    "Comission": 0,
    "DocumentCostBasis": 10000000,
    "PricePerSquareMeter": 166666.66666666666666666667,
    "Street": "Street 1",
    "ZipCode": "0682",
    "BuyerIds": [],
    "ResponsibleBrokerId": 0,
    "BrokerId": 0
  },
  {
    "Id": 669,
    "ProjectId": 667,
    "NumberOfBedrooms": 2,
    "NumberOfBedroomsMax": 2,
    "FloorSpace": 0,
    "FloorSpaceMax": 100,
    "PrimaryRoomSpace": 90,
    "PrimaryRoomSpaceMax": 90,
    "ApartmentNumber": "L-107\r",
    "CaseStatusId": 207,
    "CaseStatusType": "Active",
    "CaseStatusName": "Oppdrag akseptert",
    "CaseReferralKey": "80-17-10007",
    "StoreyOf": 1,
    "EnergyLabel": "None",
    "HeatingGrade": "None",
    "Comission": 0,
    "DocumentCostBasis": 0,
    "Street": "Street 2",
    "ZipCode": "0682",
    "BuyerIds": [],
    "ResponsibleBrokerId": 0,
    "BrokerId": 0
  },
  {
    "Id": 670,
    "ProjectId": 667,
    "NumberOfBedrooms": 2,
    "NumberOfBedroomsMax": 2,
    "FloorSpace": 0,
    "FloorSpaceMax": 100,
    "PrimaryRoomSpace": 90,
    "PrimaryRoomSpaceMax": 90,
    "ApartmentNumber": "L-106\r",
    "CaseStatusId": 223,
    "CaseStatusType": "General",
    "CaseStatusName": "Bestilt info",
    "CaseReferralKey": "80-17-10006",
    "StoreyOf": 1,
    "EnergyLabel": "None",
    "HeatingGrade": "None",
    "Comission": 0,
    "DocumentCostBasis": 0,
    "Street": "Street 1",
    "ZipCode": "0682",
    "BuyerIds": [],
    "ResponsibleBrokerId": 0,
    "BrokerId": 0
  },
  {
    "Id": 671,
    "ProjectId": 667,
    "NumberOfBedroomsMax": 1,
    "FloorSpace": 0,
    "FloorSpaceMax": 50,
    "ApartmentNumber": "L-102\r",
    "CaseStatusId": 219,
    "CaseStatusType": "General",
    "CaseStatusName": "All info mottatt",
    "CaseReferralKey": "80-17-10002",
    "StoreyOf": 2,
    "EnergyLabel": "None",
    "HeatingGrade": "None",
    "Comission": 0,
    "DocumentCostBasis": 0,
    "PricePerSquareMeter": 0,
    "Street": "Street 1",
    "ZipCode": "0682",
    "BuyerIds": [],
    "ResponsibleBrokerId": 0,
    "BrokerId": 0
  }
]

const whitelist = ["ApartmentNumber", "FloorSpace", "PrimaryRoomSpace", "CaseStatusType", "AskingPrice"];

raw.forEach(obj => {
  const filtered = whitelist.reduce((acc, key) => {
    if(key in obj) {
      acc[key] = obj[key]
    } else {
      acc[key] = null
    }
    return acc
  }, {})


  console.log(filtered);
})
```

Comment: I guess, that's not the desired result the OP wants.

Comment: @RaghavGarg yup, you were right. I understood it completely different. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more simple way.

```js
var input = [
 {
  "Id" : 668,
  "ProjectId" : 667,
  "NumberOfBedrooms" : 2,
  "FloorSpace" : 60,
  "PrimaryRoomSpace" : 60,
  "LandLotType" : "None",
  "ApartmentNumber" : "L-101\r",
  "PublicationTitle" : "L-101",
  "PublicationInformationId" : 49,
  "CaseStatusId" : 227,
  "CaseStatusType" : "Ready",
  "CaseStatusName" : "Salgsklar",
  "CaseReferralKey" : "80-17-10001",
  "AskingPrice" : 10000000,
  "EnergyLabel" : "None",
  "HeatingGrade" : "None",
  "Comission" : 0,
  "DocumentCostBasis" : 10000000,
  "PricePerSquareMeter" : 166666.66666666666666666667,
  "Street" : "Street 1",
  "ZipCode" : "0682",
  "BuyerIds" : [],
  "ResponsibleBrokerId" : 0,
  "BrokerId" : 0
 },
 {
  "Id" : 669,
  "ProjectId" : 667,
  "NumberOfBedrooms" : 2,
  "NumberOfBedroomsMax" : 2,
  "FloorSpace" : 0,
  "FloorSpaceMax" : 100,
  "PrimaryRoomSpace" : 90,
  "PrimaryRoomSpaceMax" : 90,
  "ApartmentNumber" : "L-107\r",
  "CaseStatusId" : 207,
  "CaseStatusType" : "Active",
  "CaseStatusName" : "Oppdrag akseptert",
  "CaseReferralKey" : "80-17-10007",
  "StoreyOf" : 1,
  "EnergyLabel" : "None",
  "HeatingGrade" : "None",
  "Comission" : 0,
  "DocumentCostBasis" : 0,
  "Street" : "Street 2",
  "ZipCode" : "0682",
  "BuyerIds" : [],
  "ResponsibleBrokerId" : 0,
  "BrokerId" : 0
 },
 {
  "Id" : 670,
  "ProjectId" : 667,
  "NumberOfBedrooms" : 2,
  "NumberOfBedroomsMax" : 2,
  "FloorSpace" : 0,
  "FloorSpaceMax" : 100,
  "PrimaryRoomSpace" : 90,
  "PrimaryRoomSpaceMax" : 90,
  "ApartmentNumber" : "L-106\r",
  "CaseStatusId" : 223,
  "CaseStatusType" : "General",
  "CaseStatusName" : "Bestilt info",
  "CaseReferralKey" : "80-17-10006",
  "StoreyOf" : 1,
  "EnergyLabel" : "None",
  "HeatingGrade" : "None",
  "Comission" : 0,
  "DocumentCostBasis" : 0,
  "Street" : "Street 1",
  "ZipCode" : "0682",
  "BuyerIds" : [],
  "ResponsibleBrokerId" : 0,
  "BrokerId" : 0
 },
 {
  "Id" : 671,
  "ProjectId" : 667,
  "NumberOfBedroomsMax" : 1,
  "FloorSpace" : 0,
  "FloorSpaceMax" : 50,
  "ApartmentNumber" : "L-102\r",
  "CaseStatusId" : 219,
  "CaseStatusType" : "General",
  "CaseStatusName" : "All info mottatt",
  "CaseReferralKey" : "80-17-10002",
  "StoreyOf" : 2,
  "EnergyLabel" : "None",
  "HeatingGrade" : "None",
  "Comission" : 0,
  "DocumentCostBasis" : 0,
  "PricePerSquareMeter" : 0,
  "Street" : "Street 1",
  "ZipCode" : "0682",
  "BuyerIds" : [],
  "ResponsibleBrokerId" : 0,
  "BrokerId" : 0
 }
];
var whitelist = [
 "ApartmentNumber",
 "FloorSpace",
 "PrimaryRoomSpace",
 "CaseStatusType",
 "AskingPrice"
];
var output = input.map((item) => {
 var out = {};
 whitelist.forEach((key) => {
  out[key] = key in item ? item[key] : '';
 });
 return out;
});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well instead of looping throught `Object.keys(raw)` loop throught `allowed` keys, this way you will make sure to preserve all the allowed properties.

```
const filtered = {}

allowed.forEach((key) => {
  filtered[key] = (typeof raw[key] !== 'undefined') ? raw[key] : '';
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
const raw = {
  item1: {
    key: 'sdfd',
    value: 'sdfd'
  },
  item2: {
    key: 'sdfd',
    value: 'sdfd'
  },
  item3: {
    key: 'sdfd',
    value: 'sdfd'
  }
};

const allowed = ['item1', 'item3', 'item4'];

const filtered = {}

allowed.forEach((key) => {
  filtered[key] = (typeof raw[key] !== 'undefined') ? raw[key] : '';
});

console.log(filtered);
```