# Use Object keys as dates to get average of values

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have an object like so. They key is a timestamp and the value is my number

```
var history = {
     '1505845390000': 295426,
     '1505757979000': 4115911,
     '1505677767000': 4033384,
     '1505675472000': 4033384,
     '1505591090000': 3943956,
     '1505502071000': 3848963,
     '1505499910000': 3848963,
     '1505499894000': 3848963
}
```

What I want to do is:

1) For the latest 5 dates (keys), get an average of the values
2) For a date range, get an average of the values

Comment: Have you tried to solve it yourself?

Comment: Think through what needs to be done. You need a way to iterate through every key in an object. Research Object.keys or for...in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following for the first case

```js
var obj = {
     '1505845390000': 295426,
     '1505757979000': 4115911,
     '1505677767000': 4033384,
     '1505675472000': 4033384,
     '1505591090000': 3943956,
     '1505502071000': 3848963,
     '1505499910000': 3848963,
     '1505499894000': 3848963
}

let ans = Object.keys(obj).sort();

ans = ans.slice(ans.length-5).reduce((a, b) => a+obj[b], 0);

console.log(ans/5);
```

For the 2nd case you can do

```js
var obj = {
     '1505845390000': 295426,
     '1505757979000': 4115911,
     '1505677767000': 4033384,
     '1505675472000': 4033384,
     '1505591090000': 3943956,
     '1505502071000': 3848963,
     '1505499910000': 3848963,
     '1505499894000': 3848963
}

let start = '1505591090000', end = '1505845390000'
let ans = Object.keys(obj).filter(e => e>=start && e<=end);

let result = ans.reduce((a,b) => a+obj[b],0)/ans.length

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Ahh!  I've been trying to convert it to dates and then order them.  It never occurred to just sort it first!

Comment: How could I adapt the second one to say,  filter between start and end, but only where a value is greater than 0. I have an issue where if i have a number of key/values where the value i 0, the average is affected so need to ignore the 0's

Comment: Add that condition in the filter

Comment: I dont think thats posssible as you can only access the key and not values?

Comment: if you know the key the obj[key] would give you the value

Comment: Oh wow, total brainfart moment.  `e>=start && e<=end && obj[e] != 0` thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This answer has a good explanation of how to filter an object by its keys:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38750895/5009210

Basically use `Object.keys()` to get an array of keys, then `Array.filter()` to select the ones you want, then `Array.reduce()` to reconstruct an object with the relevant values for the filtered keys. Like this:

```
Object.keys( history )
   .filter( someFilterFunction )
   .reduce( (obj, key) => {
      obj[key] = history[key];
   }, {});
```

Once you've done this, you can extract the remaining values using `Object.values()` and then pass them to a simple average function (I assume you want the mean average):

```
function meanAverage( valuesToAverage ) {
    //avoid divide by zero
    if ( valuesToAverage.length ) {
       const valueSum = sum( valuesToAverage );
       return valueSum / valuesToAverage.length;
    }
    return 0;
}

function sum( valuesToSum ) {
   return valuesToSum.reduce( (a, b) => a + b );
}
```