# Is there a way to destructure an object into a new object in es6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

For instance, I have this object:

```
const payload = {
    apple: 1,
    dog: 2,
    cat: 3
}
```

and I want to destructure it into a new object that only contains `apple` and `dog`:

```
const newPayload = {
    apple:1,
    dog: 2
}
```

Something like:

```
const {{apple, dog} : newPayload} = payload
```

Obviously the above is wrong, but wondering if there is a way to do something like this.

Thanks!

Comment: this isn't "destructuring" (that would be converting from a tuple to individual named variables), but a shallow-copy with a property filter.

Comment: this way is ugly ... `const newPayload = (({apple, dog}) => ({apple, dog}))(payload)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter object properties by key in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6)

Comment: @Dai No, this is not duplicate of that question. This is different

Comment: the benefit of my ugly code is ... no spurious const's littering the code :p

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz how is it not a duplicate? This Q's OP wants to clone an object using only a subset of that object's properties, that's exactly what's going on in the linked QA.

Comment: OP is looking for destructing based solution, which is not there in your specified link.

Comment: a less ugly non polluting way is `const newPayload = (({ cat, ...x }) => x)(payload);`

Comment: @JaromandaX What is this technique or concept called `const newPayload = (({apple, dog}) => ({apple, dog}))(payload)`? I want to read about it and how it works. Thanks

Comment: It's an IIFE @newbie

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `delete`:

```
const newPayload = { ...payload };

delete newPayload.cat
```

Or:

```
const { cat, ...newPayload } = payload;
```

Lodash also has `omit()`:

```
const newPayload = _.omit(payload, ['cat']);
```

Comment: `const { cat, ...newPayload } = payload;` is exactly what I had in mind. Thanks!

Comment: if you want to avoid littering the context with `consts`  ... `const newPayload = (({ cat, ...x }) => x)(payload);`

Answer (score 5):

Probably in two steps:

```
const payload = {
    apple: 1,
    dog: 2,
    cat: 3
}

const { apple, dog } = payload

const newPayload = {
    apple,
    dog,
}
```

Or you can use lodash `_.pick` :

```
const newPayload = _.pick(payload, ['apple', 'dog'])
```