# Filter key from list of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I filter each key out from a list of objects in ES6? Given this original (there can be many in this list):

```
[{"x": 0, 
 "y": 0, 
 "width": 10, 
 "frame_variables": [{"lookup_type": null,"lookup_id": null}]
}]
```

I want to return this:

```
[{"x": 0, 
 "y": 0, 
 "width": 10
}]
```

I'm thinking something list this but I'm not sure on the syntax:

```
displayFrames: function () {
  return this.frames.filter(e => e.key !== 'frame_variables')
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter object properties by key in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let array = [{"x": 0, 
 "y": 0, 
 "width": 10, 
 "frame_variables": [{"lookup_type": null,"lookup_id": null}]
}];

let result = array.map(({ frame_variables, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest }));

console.log(result);
```

you need to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to transform all your elements from your array. With [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) you can separate `frame_variables` key from the rest of the object, so you just return a new object without that key.

Answer (score 2):

Filtering is for removing entire elements from an array. You can just loop over the array and call `delete` for each one.

```
for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    delete array[i].frame_variables;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```js
let data = {
  "x": 0,
  "y": 0,
  "width": 10,
  "frame_variables": [{
    "lookup_type": null,
    "lookup_id": null
  }]
};

const filterAttribute = (obj, keyToFilterOut) => (Object.keys(obj)).reduce((filteredObj, key) => {
  if (keyToFilterOut !== key) {
    filteredObj[key] = obj[key]
  }
  return filteredObj;
}, {});

console.log(filterAttribute(data, 'frame_variables'))
```

My solution doesn't mutate the original object either, instead opting to create a new one altogether - great in case you want to keep the data for other reasons