# Javascript - copy object using keys from array

Tags: javascript

I have an array with names in.

I also have an object with keys that are the same as those in the array. The object also has other keys.

I would like to copy the object but only include the keys that are in the array

```js
const keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

const obj = {
 date: 'Jan',
 color: 'Red',
 one: 367,
 two: 427,
 three: 753
}

const objCopy = Object.assign({}, obj)


// I'd like this console to display
// {
//   "one": 367,
//   "two": 427,
//   "three": 753
// }

console.log(objCopy)
```

Comment: [Filter object properties by key in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

const obj = {
 date: 'Jan',
 color: 'Red',
 one: 367,
 two: 427,
 three: 753
}

const objCopy = {};

keys.forEach(key => objCopy[key] = obj[key]);

console.log(objCopy)
```

Answer (score 4):

Very simple `reduce`.

```js
const keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

const obj = {
  date: 'Jan',
  color: 'Red',
  one: 367,
  two: 427,
  three: 753
};

const res = keys.reduce((a, c) => (obj[c] ? a[c] = obj[c] : c, a), {});
console.log(res);
```

(The ternary operator ensures that the key actually exists in the object - otherwise you'd get `undefined`s in your result that you'd have to filter out).

Answer (score 2):

Using `forEach` loop

```js
const keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

const obj = {
 date: 'Jan',
 color: 'Red',
 one: 367,
 two: 427,
 three: 753
}
var obj1={};
keys.forEach(e=>{
obj1[e]=obj[e]
})
const objCopy = Object.assign({}, obj1)
console.log(objCopy)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get the desired object using the following way:

```
const keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

const obj = {
    date: 'Jan',
    color: 'Red',
    one: 367,
    two: 427,
    three: 753
}

let desiredObject = Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(key => keys.includes(key))
    .map(key => {
        return {[key]: obj[key]}
    })
    .reduce((a, b) => Object.assign({}, a,b));
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you, you have to loop through the keys array and add grab every existing key from `obj` in order to construct your new object. Which is not a copy, it's a new object with your desired keys.

```js
const keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

const obj = {
 date: 'Jan',
 color: 'Red',
 one: 367,
 two: 427,
 three: 753
}

const objCopy = {};

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  objCopy[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i]];
}

console.log(objCopy)
```

You don't need to use any other fancy methods to do this, other methods will indeed reduce the number of the code lines but will decrease your performance, like using `.reduce()` or other `Array` methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reduce` on the keys array to get the desired object.

```js
const keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

const obj = {
 date: 'Jan',
 color: 'Red',
 one: 367,
 two: 427,
 three: 753
}

const objCopy = keys.reduce((a,e) => {
  a[e] = obj[e];
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(objCopy)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cont objCopy = Object.entries(obj).reduce(([key, value],acc)=>keys.includes(key)?{...acc, key:value}:acc, {})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `hasOwnProperty` is used to exclude inherited properties

```js
const keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

const obj = {
  date: 'Jan',
  color: 'Red',
  one: 367,
  two: 427,
  three: 753
}

const objCopy = {}; // copy

for (let property in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property) && keys.find(k => k == property)) {
    objCopy[property] = obj[property];
  }
}

console.log(objCopy);
```

Comment: +1 for checking if it has the property. I suggested an edit to have `let` inside for loop. we should use `let` and `const` in JS and retire use of `var`

Comment: First your code is wrong - duplicated `obj` declaration. And for `object` -  it's better to use `const` than `let` if you don't need assignment another value.

Comment: @АленаВерещака I addressed your concerns

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const obj = {
 date: 'Jan',
 color: 'Red',
 one: 367,
 two: 427,
 three: 753
}

const extract = ({one, two, three}) =>Object.assign({},{one, two, three});

console.log(extract(obj))
```

Comment: It's not the answer for this Question. If you need additional property `four` then how much do you need to update?

Comment: @АленаВерещака ,add in params , ({, four}) , i use destructuring objects as function parameters in ES6..., this is solution without using any iterations (foreach, map ...)

Comment: Ahmen, thanks for your reply. I think the point of question is asking how to copy object by filtering `key` array which consist `string` keys inside. Thanks