# How does the front end handle the problem of redundant fields in the backend return data?

Tags: javascript

```
let localData = {
  name: '',
  sex: ''
}

let resData = {
  name: 'zzs',
  sex: 'boy',
  age: 18,
  birthday: '10-21',
  address: 'demo'
}

localData = resData

// { name: 'zzs',
//   sex: 'boy',
//   age: 18,
//   birthday: '10-21',
//   address: 'demo' }
console.log(localData)
```

The result I hope to get is {
Name: "zzs",
Gender: "Boy"
}

I don't want to do it in the following way.

```
localData.name = resData.name;
localData.sex = resData.sex;
```

Is there a good performance method that can be achieved?
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a subset of a javascript object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6

Answer (score 1):

You can merge your two objects using:

```
Object.keys(resData).filter(key => key in localData).forEach(key => localData[key] = resData[key]);
```

So using your example data, see the [working fiddle (open the console)](https://jsfiddle.net/r2ax84yo/), or working snippet below:

```js
let localData = {
  name: '',
  sex: ''
}

let resData = {
  name: 'zzs',
  sex: 'boy',
  age: 18,
  birthday: '10-21',
  address: 'demo'
}

Object.keys(resData).filter(key => key in localData).forEach(key => localData[key] = resData[key]);
console.log(localData)
```

**How it works:**

[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names. So in this case we find all the keys of `resData`

We then use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on our `localData` data keys, loop them using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and set their values from the corresponding `resData` key

This will work dynamically (you don't have to specify the keys you want to merge). If the same key exists in both `localData` and `resData` it will be merged into `localData`

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this code using external libraries `lodash` -

```js
let localData = {
  name: '',
  sex: ''
}

let resData = {
  name: 'zzs',
  sex: 'boy',
  age: 18,
  birthday: '10-21',
  address: 'demo'
}

localData = _.pick(resData,_.keys(localData));

console.log(localData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: You may want to *prominently* point out that this requires an external library.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
let {name,sex} = resData; //Destructure only values required
localData = {name,sex} // assign to localdata

console.log(localData) //{name: "zzs", sex: "boy"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.fromEntries()` by mapping your `localData`'s keys to take the values residing in `resData`. This will create a new object:

```js
const localData = {
  name: '',
  sex: ''
}

const resData = {
  name: 'zzs',
  sex: 'boy',
  age: 18,
  birthday: '10-21',
  address: 'demo'
}

const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(localData).map(k => [k, resData[k]]));
console.log(res);
```