# Filtering JSON array using matching strings from another array

Tags: typescript

I have a master list to refer and filter from:

```
nvMaster: [
    {"1": "One"},
    {"2": "TWO"},
    {"3": "THREE"},
    {"4":"FOUR"},
    {"5":"FIVE"}

];
```

I have second array of permitted values form final JSON.

```
nvPermitted:["1","3","5"];
```

I need to form a final array like below:

```
nvFinal: [
    {"1": "One"},       
    {"3": "THREE"},
    {"5":"FIVE"}
];
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? I'm removing the Angular tag as this is just a TS problem. Thanks.

Comment: This code `nvPermitted:{"1","3","5"};` is not valid

Comment: @ggorlen if it is Angular not angularJS this will subject to typescript not Javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter object properties by key in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6)

Comment: @Dalorzo excellent point, updated.

Comment: nvPermitted is updated in the post...Thanks.

Comment: Tried ->  const nvFinal = Object.keys(this.nvMaster)
  .filter(key => this.nvPermitted.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = this.nvMaster[key];
   // console.log("json:",JSON.stringify(obj))
    return obj;
  }, {}); This gives issue @includes(key) ->arguement of type string is not assignable to to parameter of type '"1" | "3" | "5"

Answer (score 0):

You may want to refactor your code like that

```js
nvMaster: [
    "One",
    "TWO",
    "THREE",
    "FOUR",
    "FIVE"
];
nvPermitted:[0, 2, 4]; // arr start at 0
nvFinal: nvMaster.reduce((acc, val, idx) => {
    if (nvPermitted.indexOf(idx) > -1) {
        acc[idx + 1] = val;
    }
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: Am sorry for wrong mention of nvPermitted , which is updated in the original post...Thanks