# How to get a property of an object by string value with [index]

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings like

```
let arr = ["id", "photos[0]"]
```

And source object like

```
let obj = {
  id: 111,
  name: "nick",
  photos: [{photo1: tbd},{photo2: tbd}]
}
```

And i need to filter this obj by given strings to get new obj

```
{id: 111, photos: {photo1: tbd}}
```

any elegant solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6 <-- I believe this does what you want. Filter an object by a set of allowed properties.

Comment: Is the goal to have the string `"photos[0]"` act like code, e.g., it'll return the first element of the data's `photos` array?

Comment: @DaveNewton How is that not covered by the answers? One of the examples is `'part3[0].name'`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ah, yes. It is covered by the answers, although I think the question title should be edited to better reflect the content.

Comment: See [AngularJS has `$scope.$eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60553207/5535245) for a way to do it with AngularJS.