# How to avoid passing "key" as argument to map, reduce or filter while iterating the key value pairs using Object.entries?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was following the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6) to filter a key-value pair in JS.

I have an Object of key-value pairs.
I am trying to do something like this

```
{
   Object.entries(this.state.passengers)
      .filter(([key, passenger]) => passenger.flightNumber === this.props.flightNumber)
      .map(([key, passenger]) => {
         return ( 
            <tr key = {key}>
            //...JSX code
         )
      })
}
```

I get the warnings in console that key is not used. I am not finding the right syntax to avoid passing key as an argument to filter method. I want to pass the key to subsequent map method though. Please help. I am new to JS.

Comment: You can use `Object.values` if you just want the values, then grab the value in your callback like so: `passenger =>`

Comment: @NickParsons, I edited my question. What should I do if I want to pass it to map method?

Comment: I see now, you can try replace `key` with `_` in your filter method - `_` is commonly used to denote unused arguments, so your console may not complain about it - otherwise, you could get the `Object.keys()` from your object, and get the value using the key `this.state.passengers[key]` if you're really worried about solving the warning

Comment: ```.filter``` does not require key, but ```.map``` does, and you are already passing the key correctly to the element. So just remove ```key``` from ```.filter```

Comment: @NickParsons  same warning : warning  '_' is defined but never used

Comment: @MohammedShirhaan one other idea may be to not to define a variable for the first array slot, so `([, passenger]) =>` might remove the warning?

Comment: @NickParsons, I tried the same. It is working. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here, the easiest would most likely be to [ignore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Ignoring_some_returned_values) the first array value in your destructuring assignment so that `key` is never defined in your `.map()` callback in the first place:

```
.map(([, passenger]) => {
```

Additionally, another approach may be to use `Object.keys()`, and then get the value via the `key`:

```
Object.keys(this.state.passengers)
  .filter(key => this.state.passengers[key].flightNumber === this.props.flightNumber)
  .map(key => {
    return ( 
      <tr key = {key}>
      //...JSX code
    )
  })
```