# How to exclude key in object with map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object

```js
{
   id: 10, 
   email: "test@gmail.com", 
   roles: Array(1), 
   firstName: "toto", 
   lastName: "tata"
}
```

I would like to display only `test@gmail.com,` `toto`, `tata`  and exclude `id` and `role`

So I did this but I don't know how to exclude id and role. I tried with filter but it's not working..
Does anyone know how to do that?

```js
const datas = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
   return (
      <div key={key.id}>
         <p>
            {value}
         </p>
      </div>
   );
});
```

Comment: `filter` should just work as intended. How is it not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter object properties by key in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter` to filter out the ones you dont want:

```js
const datas = Object.entries(data)
  .filter(([key]) => key !== 'id' && key !== 'role')
  .map(([key, value]) => {
    return (
      <div key={key.id}>
        <p>
          {value}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  });
```

Comment: With a little shorter syntax `.filter(key => !['id','role'].includes(key))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it still displays id and role :/

Comment: Corrected the filter; should have used `([key])` to get the key.

Answer (score 2):

It is a good place to use `Array.filter`, but if you know which fields you want to show and there are only three you can do it like this:

```
  const { email, firstName, lastName } = data;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {email}
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>
        {firstName}
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>
        {lastName}
      </p>
    </div>
   );
```

The key is not needed. Also I'm not sure if `key.id` is a valid parameter here, I think that we are receiving a string, not an object from the `Object.entries` array.

The approach I showed is more descriptive, does not use a loop and it is easier to add `<a>` for an email or put full name (first and last name) in one `<h1>` HTML tag.