# Remove objects from an Array based on values in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create an array with 7 objects (each per day). Idea is to create store hours for 7 days.

Final Dictionary will be like this:

```
    const storeHours = {
      monday: { startTime: mondayTime1, endTime: mondayTime1 },
      tuesday: { startTime: new Date(), endTime: new Date() },
      wednesday: { startTime: new Date(), endTime: new Date() },
//  other days ...
    };
```

I have 7 checkboxes, one for each day.

When I click checkbox, it stores checked item in an array.

```
checkedValues = ["Friday", "Saturday"]
```

I can use this checkedValues items to know which entry to make in newDict.

like this:

```
newDict = {
monday: { startTime: mondayTime1, endTime: mondayTime1 },
}
```

When I click second checkbox, newDict should have new entry for that day and so on.

When I un-check the checkbox I have to also remove the entry from this dictionary, so both, checkbox and dictionary, remain in sync.

how do I remove an entry from dictionary when an item is un-checked?

Whole idea is to basically store store hours in database with dictionary with 7 objects..

Comment: Use `Array.filter`

Comment: `finalArray ` is not an _array_: you have created an array containing a single dictionary and you have saved entries in the dictionary. This seems inefficient. Just create a dictionary, remove square brackets: `finalArray = {...}`

Comment: Do you still have `checkedValues`?

Comment: yes I still have checkedValues array that holds checked items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you still have the array with `checkedValues` you can use `.filter()` and then `.reduce()` to leave only the days from `checkedValues`. Also, you can use `Object.keys()` which will return the names of `storeHours`'s keys.

```js
const checkedValues = ["monday", "tuesday"];

const storeHours = {
  monday: { startTime: 1, endTime: 3 },
  tuesday: { startTime: new Date(), endTime: new Date() },
  wednesday: { startTime: new Date(), endTime: new Date() },
  //  other days ...
};

const newDict = Object.keys(storeHours)
  .filter(day => checkedValues.includes(day))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = storeHours[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});;

console.log(newDict);
```

This returns:

```js
{
  "monday": {
    "startTime": 1,
    "endTime": 3
  },
  "tuesday": {
    "startTime": "2020-07-27T06:50:27.858Z",
    "endTime": "2020-07-27T06:50:27.858Z"
  }
}
```

[More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6) on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here, please edit your question to make it more clear. So, as far as I can understand, here is a possible solution.

#### 1. Store your entries in a dictionary

As your code is right now, `finalArray` is an array containing a single dictionary that you use to store entries. That is inefficient, just use the dictionary:

```
finalDict = {
  Friday: {startTime: startTime}, 
  Saturday: {endTime: endTime}
}
```

And since it is not an array, but a dictionary, I have renamed it accordingly to avoid confusion.

#### 2. Set the entry to `null`

The cool thing of using dictionaries, is that you can reference an entry by its name. So, if `Saturday` is marked, then you need to simple:

```
finalDict.Saturday = null;
```

Or:

```
finalDict["Saturday"] = null;
```

After you do that, your dictionary will have the following value:

```
{
  Friday: {startTime: startTime}, 
  Saturday: null
}
```