# How to display only needed value pair from an object?

Tags: javascript

This is my object:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 11,
        "name": null,
        "email": null,
        "phone": "000000000",
        "age": null,
        "role": "user",
        "otp": "656440",
        "otpCreatedAt": null,
        "createdAt": "2020-10-24T07:38:54.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-10-24T07:38:54.000Z"
    }
}
```

Am getting this from querying on mysql db, now i dont want to send all the values to response ! Instead i need selected values to be sent under a single key !

Expected output

```
{
    "user" :{
        "name": null,
        "email": null,
        "phone": "000000000",
        "age": null,
      }
}
```

I can split this and send like `name: user.name` etc but i need all the needed under single key !

How to achieve this ?

As of now am just splitting it like this !

```
phone: user.phone, name: user.name, age: user.age, email: user.email
```

Comment: `const {name, email, phone, age} = input.user, output = {user: {name, email, phone, age}};`

Comment: Duplicate of [Filter object properties by key in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply construct a new object with the keys/values you need from the old object.

```js
let u = {
    "user": {
        "id": 11,
        "name": null,
        "email": null,
        "phone": "000000000",
        "age": null,
        "role": "user",
        "otp": "656440",
        "otpCreatedAt": null,
        "createdAt": "2020-10-24T07:38:54.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-10-24T07:38:54.000Z"
    }
}

let newuser = {user: {name: u.user.name, email: u.user.email, phone: u.user.phone, age: u.user.age}};
console.log(newuser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be a good solution? I would like to take this way.

```
const { user: { name, email, phone, age } } = {
    "user": {
        "id": 11,
        "name": null,
        "email": null,
        "phone": "000000000",
        "age": null,
        "role": "user",
        "otp": "656440",
        "otpCreatedAt": null,
        "createdAt": "2020-10-24T07:38:54.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-10-24T07:38:54.000Z"
    }
};

const expectedResult = {
  "user": { name, email, phone, age }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Properties can be excluded with the [`JSON.parse` reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) and the [`JSON.stringify` replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) :

```js
var o = { "user": { "id": 11, "name": null, "email": null, "phone": "000000000", "age": null, "role": "user", "otp": "656440", "otpCreatedAt": null, "createdAt": "2020-10-24T07:38:54.000Z", "updatedAt": "2020-10-24T07:38:54.000Z" } }

var j = JSON.stringify(o, (k, v) => /^(|user|name|email|phone|age)$/.test(k) ? v : undefined, 2)

console.log(j)
```