# How to get the keys and then remove the keys not associated to an array?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the values of the items then remove the keys not associated to the columns

Below is my code

```
var columns =['title','code','notes','value','daysCode'];

var items =[{
        title:'Marvel',
        code:'marvel-01',
        notes:'spider-man',
        value:'Value 2',
        daysCode:'Sept 1, 2020',
        daysAge:'Nov 1 , 2019',
        name:'Peter Parker',
        other:'comic'
    },
    {
        title:'DC',
        code:'dc-01',
        notes:'batman',
        value:'Value 1',
        daysCode:'Sept 1, 2020',
        daysAge:'Nov 1 , 2019',
        name:'Bruce Wayne',
        other:'comics'
    },
    {
        title:'Image',
        code:'image-02',
        notes:'spawn',
        value:'Value 3',
        daysCode:'Sept 1, 2020',
        daysAge:'Nov 1 , 2019',
        name:'Albert Simmons',
        other:'comics'
    }
]
```

**Output:**

```
newItems = [{
    title:'Marvel',
    code:'marvel-01',
    notes:'spider-man',
    value:'Value 2',
    daysCode:'Sept 1, 2020'
},
{
   title:'DC',
   code:'dc-01',
   notes:'batman',
   value:'Value 1',
   daysCode:'Sept 1, 2020'
},
{
   title:'Image',
   code:'image-02',
   notes:'spawn',
   value:'Value 3',
   daysCode:'Sept 1, 2020'
}]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Or [ecmascript 6 - Filter object properties by key in ES6 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6)

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. You should post the code you have written so far so site users can see what exactly you are trying to do and where it is going wrong.

Comment: @user202729 In such cases you mark the question as dupe

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I know about that. But since there are more than one I'm just checking which one is better and stuff... (besides I only have a flag)

Comment: The easy and short answer would be -

    const result = items.map(item => {
      return (({title,code,notes,value,daysCode}) => ({title,code,notes,value,daysCode}))(item)
    })
    
    
    console.log("result----",result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to get your expected output:

```js
var columns =['title','code','notes','value','daysCode'];

var items =[{ title:'Marvel', code:'marvel-01', notes:'spider-man', value:'Value 2', daysCode:'Sept 1, 2020', daysAge:'Nov 1 , 2019', name:'Peter Parker', other:'comic' }, { title:'DC', code:'dc-01', notes:'batman', value:'Value 1', daysCode:'Sept 1, 2020', daysAge:'Nov 1 , 2019', name:'Bruce Wayne', other:'comics' }, { title:'Image', code:'image-02', notes:'spawn', value:'Value 3', daysCode:'Sept 1, 2020', daysAge:'Nov 1 , 2019', name:'Albert Simmons', other:'comics' } ]

var newItems = items.map(o=>Object.fromEntries(columns.map(n=>[n,o[n]])));

// using reduce method:
var newItems1 = items.map(o=>columns.reduce((a,e)=>({...a, [e]:o[e]}),{}));

console.log(newItems);
console.log(newItems1);
```

Comment: Is there a way that not using Object.fromEntries?

Comment: @thePeculiarCoder yes, use `reduce` then

Comment: @thePeculiarCoder Please check the updated duplicates. You could use reduce to create a subset of each object https://stackoverflow.com/a/32184094/3082296

Comment: @thePeculiarCoder If you had specific requirements, you should have specified it in the question.