# Object destructuring adds unxexpected key:value pair

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, destructuring

I'm using destructuring of `req.body` to get all the field inputs.
But for some reason, the `_csrf` token gets passed in??

Here's the code:

```
 let bizReq = {
        logo,
        category,
        name,
        owner,
        phone,
        location,
        website,
        email,
      } = req.body;

    /// EG result (console.log(bizReq);)
    new biz:  {
      name: 'Jasmine Gregory',
      email: 'sojopo@mailinator.com',
      location: 'Itaque aperiam iusto',
      owner: { firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Garrett' },
      phone: '+1 523 308-3805',
      website: 'https://www.kezobazi.cm',
      category: 'Clothes',
      logo: 'https://eu.ui-avatars.com/api/? 
      background=89023E&color=fff&name=Jasmine+Gregory&length=2&size=512',
      _csrf: 'ATqvC5qR-h1JPRec_usro3V4Pb6jYv80Tj5Y' ----------????---------
   }
```

Where am I going wrong here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think this is possible, unless you're logging the wrong object? Also what does the `new` before `biz:` mean?

Comment: You're not using proper syntax `let newObj = {prop1, prop2} = obj`. This means `let newObj = obj`

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee I didn't spot the second equals.

Comment: OP, try removing `bizReq =` and the destructuring should work as expected

Comment: @evolutionxbox It's what gets console.logged  `console.log("new biz: ", bizReq);`

Comment: @MendiSterenfeld there's no reason to have that variable when you already have `req.body`

Comment: I think what he expects is that bizReq only contains the "destructured bits" rather than the entire contents of req.body, however it doesn't work like that.  The destructuring part in the middle is only a destructuring device and not an object representation (ie it's not an object that you could assign to bizReq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not quite proper object destructuring.

Here is an example so that you know where you went wrong:

```js
let obj = { a, b } = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
console.log(obj); // will print { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

The `let` statement above is equivalent to:

```js
let obj = ( { a, b } = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 } );
```

Assignment expressions in JS (expressions that look like `p = q`) will always return the right hand side of the expression. This is so that equal operators can be chained. The expression `r = p = q` is parsed as `r = (p = q)`, and in order for both `r` and `p` to be assigned `q`, `(p = q)` must return `q`.

This means that the expression `{ a, b } = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }` will *always return* `{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }`. Consequently, the code is equivalent to

```js
let obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
```

and there's your mistake.

If you want to limit the keys a certain object has, check out ["Filter object properties by key in ES6"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to filter out certain properties from an object consider using [`Rest Parameter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

**Note:** `let newObj = {prop1, prop2} = obj` is equivalent to `let newObj = obj`.

```js
const data = {
  name: "Jasmine Gregory",
  email: "sojopo@mailinator.com",
  location: "Itaque aperiam iusto",
  owner: { firstName: "Mary", lastName: "Garrett" },
  phone: "+1 523 308-3805",
  website: "https://www.kezobazi.cm",
  category: "Clothes",
  logo: "https://eu.ui-avatars.com/api/?",
  background: "89023E&color=fff&name=Jasmine+Gregory&length=2&size=512",
  _csrf: "ATqvC5qR-h1JPRec_usro3V4Pb6jYv80Tj5Y",
};

let {_csrf, ...bizReq} = data;

console.log(bizReq);
```

If you want to be safe and destructure only the properties that you want, avoiding the risk of including any malicious data present in `req.body`.

You can first `destructure` the required properties out of `req.body` and then construct the `bizReq` variable using these properties.

```
let { name, email, location, owner, phone, website, category, logo, background } = data;
let bizReq = { name, email, location, owner, phone, website, category, logo, background }
```

Or if you're into one liners like me, you can use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```js
const data = {
  name: "Jasmine Gregory",
  email: "sojopo@mailinator.com",
  location: "Itaque aperiam iusto",
  owner: { firstName: "Mary", lastName: "Garrett" },
  phone: "+1 523 308-3805",
  website: "https://www.kezobazi.cm",
  category: "Clothes",
  logo: "https://eu.ui-avatars.com/api/?",
  background: "89023E&color=fff&name=Jasmine+Gregory&length=2&size=512",
  _csrf: "ATqvC5qR-h1JPRec_usro3V4Pb6jYv80Tj5Y",
};

let bizReq = (
  ({name, email, location, owner, phone, website, category, logo, background}) => 
  ({name,email,location,owner,phone,website,category,logo,background})
)(data);

console.log(bizReq);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that other (malicious) key-value pairs can be added to the `...bizReq` object.

Comment: @MendiSterenfeld Nice point! I've updated my answer addressing the same.

Comment: Thanks for the IIFE, can you explain to me what's going on there? ;--)

Comment: @MendiSterenfeld Created an anonymous function and immediately called it passing in `data` as an argument. Now, in the function parameter destructured the desired properties and then finally returned an object containing all the properties.