# carrying previous state except for one value in useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [filters,filtersSetter]=useState({});

function setNewSearchQuery(param,value) {

 filtersSetter(preval=>({...preval,[param]:value}))
}
```

In my `useState`, if i want to keep everything in `preval` except for one key in my JSON object what do i do?
i want to remove the key and its value basically, all in one line as opposed to breaking down the object first then applying changes. That is how we update the current state, is there a way to remove one from it?
example

```
filters={ username="sample" , role="roleSample"}
```

when given `username` i want to be left with

```
    filters={ role="roleSample"}
```

Comment: Just make a copy of the object with spread operator (while remembering spread only does shallow copy) then use the `delete` keyword to remove the desired property. If you're already using a library like lodash in your project it has an `omit` function that'll do this for you

Comment: What is the key you're trying to remove? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: My quick guess: `filtersSetter(({ removedKey, ...rest }) =>({ ...rest, [param]: value }))`

Comment: @EmileBergeron just added an example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter object properties by key in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6)