# How can i get a new Array with only the object keys i want from an Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do i get only the obj keys i want, in a array of objects?

I have an array of keys and an array of objects.

```
let myKeys = ['first_name', 'last_name']

let myArray = [
{
 id: 1,
 fist_name: 'John',
 last_name: 'Paul',
 age: 22,
 city: 'New York'
},
{
 id: 1,
 fist_name: 'John',
 last_name: 'Paul',
 age: 22,
 city: 'New York'
},
{
 id: 1,
 fist_name: 'John',
 last_name: 'Paul',
 age: 22,
 city: 'New York'
},
]
```

How can i turn myArray into a new array based on 'myKeys'?
Like below:

```
[
{
 first_name: 'John',
 last_name: 'Paul'
},
{
 first_name: 'John',
 last_name: 'Paul'
},
{
 first_name: 'John',
 last_name: 'Paul'
},
{
 first_name: 'John',
 last_name: 'Paul'
},
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter object properties by key in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
let myKeys = ['first_name', 'last_name'];
let myArray=[{id:1,first_name:"John",last_name:"Paul",age:22,city:"New York"},{id:1,first_name:"John",last_name:"Paul",age:22,city:"New York"},{id:1,first_name:"John",last_name:"Paul",age:22,city:"New York"}];
let res = myArray.map(x => Object.fromEntries(myKeys.map(k => [k, x[k]])));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Unmitigated, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve the result.

```
const result = myArray.map((obj) => {
  return myKeys.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = obj[curr];
    return acc;
  }, {});
});
```

```js
let myKeys = ["first_name", "last_name"];

let myArray = [{
    id: 1,
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Paul",
    age: 22,
    city: "New York",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Paul",
    age: 22,
    city: "New York",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Paul",
    age: 22,
    city: "New York",
  },
];

const result = myArray.map((obj) => {
  return myKeys.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = obj[curr];
    return acc;
  }, {});
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are not running on strict mode...

```
function reduceProp(objects, pops){
     let template = {};
     props.forEach((prop)=>{template[prop]="";}));
     Object.seal(template);
     return objects.map(object=>Object.assign( template, object));
}
```