# How select items in an object from an array of undesired key and create a new object with the result

Tags: javascript, object, iteration, filtered

Maybe it's a weird question, and maybe that exists and other way to make that... But, I've an initial Object on which I iterate on the key.
For a special task, I've needed to have this Object without some key:value.
For doing that I make an object with the key that I don't want.

I make this code pen for sample: https://codepen.io/charlene-bx/pen/qBXaqEL

```
const myInitialObject = {
  'key#one' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#two' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#three' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#four' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#five' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#six' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#seven' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#eight' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#nine' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#ten' : 'dataofanotherObject'
}

const unDesiredKey = [
  'one',
  'four',
  'six'
]

// expected output:
// {
//  'key#two' : 'dataofanotherObject',
//  'key#three' : 'dataofanotherObject',
//  'key#five' : 'dataofanotherObject',
//  'key#seven' : 'dataofanotherObject',
//  'key#eight' : 'dataofanotherObject',
//  'key#nine' : 'dataofanotherObject',
//  'key#ten' : 'dataofanotherObject'
// }
```

I've found this solution but I can't find it very readable:

```
const filteredObject = Object.keys(myInitialObject)
      .filter(key => !unDesiredKey.map( el => !key.includes(el)).some(el => el===false))
      .reduce((accumulator, value) => ({...accumulator, [value]: myInitialObject[value]}), {})
```

Comment: [This link should help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this,

Use `Array.prototype.map()` on `Object.entires()` to filter out an array of desired key-value pair. And finally construct a new object from the key-value pair using `Object.fromEntries()`

```js
const myInitialObject = {
    'key#one': 'dataofanotherObject',
    'key#two': 'dataofanotherObject',
    'key#three': 'dataofanotherObject',
    'key#four': 'dataofanotherObject',
    'key#five': 'dataofanotherObject',
    'key#six': 'dataofanotherObject',
    'key#seven': 'dataofanotherObject',
    'key#eight': 'dataofanotherObject',
    'key#nine': 'dataofanotherObject',
    'key#ten': 'dataofanotherObject'
}

const unDesiredKey = [
    'one',
    'four',
    'six'
]

const arr = Object.entries(myInitialObject).filter(x => !unDesiredKey.includes(x[0].split('#')[1]));

const finalObj = Object.fromEntries(arr);
console.log(finalObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `filter` the objects `entries` by keeping the ones that evaluate `falsy` to `find(x => k.includes(x))` and use them to create a new object `fromEntries`.

```js
const myInitialObject = {
  'key#one': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#two': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#three': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#four': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#five': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#six': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#seven': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#eight': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#nine': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#ten': 'dataofanotherObject'
}

const unDesiredKey = [
  'one',
  'four',
  'six'
];

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(myInitialObject)
  .filter(([k]) => !unDesiredKey.find(x => k.includes(x)))
);

console.log(result);
```

I could also accomplish this with `reduce()` if you like.

```js
const obj = {
  'key#one': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#two': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#three': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#four': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#five': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#six': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#seven': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#eight': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#nine': 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#ten': 'dataofanotherObject'
}

const unDesiredKey = [
  'one',
  'four',
  'six'
];

const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
  if (unDesiredKey.find(x => k.includes(x))) return acc;
  acc = { ...acc, [k]: v }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the entries and slice the key for comparing.

```js
const
    data = { 'key#one': 'dataofanotherObject', 'key#two': 'dataofanotherObject', 'key#three': 'dataofanotherObject', 'key#four': 'dataofanotherObject', 'key#five': 'dataofanotherObject', 'key#six': 'dataofanotherObject', 'key#seven': 'dataofanotherObject', 'key#eight': 'dataofanotherObject', 'key#nine': 'dataofanotherObject', 'key#ten': 'dataofanotherObject' },
    unDesiredKey = ['one', 'four', 'six'],
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(data)
        .filter(([key]) => !unDesiredKey.includes(key.slice(key.indexOf('#') + 1)))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided approach uses the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method's accumulating object as carrier for the final `result` and `omissibles` as inexpensive/fast lookup structure (instead of e.g. an array based `includes` or `find`) for an undesired key ...

```js
const myInitialObject = {
  'key#one' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#two' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#three' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#four' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#five' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#six' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#seven' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#eight' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#nine' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#ten' : 'dataofanotherObject',
};
const unDesiredKey = [
  'one',
  'four',
  'six',
];

console.log(
  Object
    .entries(myInitialObject)
    .reduce(({ omissibles, result }, [key, value]) => ({

      omissibles,
      result: (key.split('#')[1] in omissibles)
        ? result
        : Object.assign(result, { [key]: value }),

    }), {

      omissibles: Object.fromEntries(unDesiredKey.map(key => [key, true])),
      result: {},

    }).result
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The lookup based approach also works for filtering the wanted entries (skipping the undesired ones) by providing the lookup as second [`thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#parameters) property to the entry [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)ing task which results in a leaner code than the one above ...

```js
const myInitialObject = {
  'key#one' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#two' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#three' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#four' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#five' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#six' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#seven' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#eight' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#nine' : 'dataofanotherObject',
  'key#ten' : 'dataofanotherObject',
};
const unDesiredKey = [
  'one',
  'four',
  'six',
];

console.log(
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object
      .entries(myInitialObject)
      .filter(function getValidEntryByBoundOmissibleKeys ([key]) {

        return !(key.split('#')[1] in this);

      }, Object.fromEntries(unDesiredKey.map(key => [key, true])))
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```