# How to get multiple fields from object?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an observable that contains some data.

I also have a method that gets 1 specific field:

```
getField(fieldName: string) {
 return this.response$.asObservable().
  pipe(
    map(data => data[fieldName]),
    take(1)
  )
} 

------------------------------------------------

getFirstNameGroup(): Observable<any> {
   return this.service.getField('first_name'); // returns current field's properties as an object
}
```

I want to pass not only one field name but many, something like this:

```
getFields(fieldNames: string[]) {
 return this.response$.asObservable().
  pipe(
    map(data => fieldNames.map(field => data[field])),
    take(1)
  )
}

------------------------------------------------

getPersonName(): Observable<any> {
    // returns an array of objects where indexes 0 and 1 are instead of first_name and last_name
    return this.service.getFields(['first_name', 'last_name']); 
}
```

I just can't figure out what should I change in `map()` in order to get an object that will be like (or something like this):

```
{
  first_name: {...},
  last_name: {...}
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: look into reduce instead of map

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6/38750895#38750895

Comment: Thank you both for the hints! @munleashed, it worked but Lukasz Gawrys' solution looks cleaner, I guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
map(data => fieldNames.reduce((prev, curr) => ({...prev, [curr]: data[curr]}), {} as any)),
```

**Explanation:**

Let's say `fieldNames` array looks like this `['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_no']` so now what happens in each iteration?

In each iteration we use the spread operator to merge previous value saved under `prev` with one new property.

**#1** iteration

`({ ...{}, 'first_name': data['first_name'] })`

which equals to

`{ 'first_name': {} }`

`prev` is the empty `{}` passed as last parameter to the reduce function. `[curr]` syntax let us use dynamic keys in objects so this translates just to
`'first_name'` as this is the value of `curr` at this moment.

**#2** iteration

`({ ...{'first_name': {} }, 'last_name': data['last_name'] })`

which equals to

`{ 'first_name': {}, 'last_name': {} }`

**#3** iteration

`({ ...{ 'first_name': {}, 'last_name': {} }, 'phone_no': data['phone_no'] })`

which equals to

`{ 'first_name': {}, 'last_name': {}, 'phone_no': {} }`

With each iteration `curr` gets the next element of the `fieldNames` array and `prev` the last returned value from the reduce function.

Moreover for the reduce function the [Advanced syntax of arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#advanced_syntax) is used, which let us elegantly return a literal object.

For simplicity I assume that `data` is dictionary with a key of type string and value of type object. I put just empty objects as placeholders.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! It works perfectly but 2nd arrow-function looks a bit hard for me to understand :/ gonna try to figure out

Comment: @desmondische I added some explanation in the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can use object literal syntax. Like this:

```js
map(data => ({
  first_name: data.fs,
  last_name: data.ls
}))
```

or if you prefer indexing fields on objects

```js
map(data => ({
  first_name: data[fs]
  last_name: data[ls]
}))
```

Comment: I want this method to be generic. So I could pass different fields, i.e. email, phone etc. I don't want to specify properties. I want them to be created using fieldNames parameter