# In React and Redux what is the most efficient way to map over an item's Id that is referenced in a normalised state shape?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, normalization

So I've just started learning redux and in the process read their documentation on '[Normalizing State Shape](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape)'.

One of the key takeaway points is:

> "Any references to individual items should be done by storing the item's ID."

I've set up my state as they have advised. So in the example below each taskGroup holds a selection of tasks referenced by their ids and each task holds a selection of comments also referenced by their ids.

```
{
    "taskGroups": {
        "byId": {
            "taskGroup1": {
                "taskGroupId": "taskGroup1",
                "tasks": ["task1", "task2"]
                //etc etc
            },
            "taskGroup2": {
                "taskGroupId": "taskGroup2",
                "tasks": ["task2", "task3"]
                //etc etc
            }
            //etc etc
        },
        "allIds": ["taskGroup1", "taskGroup2", "taskGroup3"]
    },
    "tasks": {
        "byId": {
            "task1": {
                "taskId": "task1",
                "description": "......",
                "comments": ["comment1", "comment2"]
                //etc etc
            },
            "task2": {
                "taskId": "task2",
                "description": "......",
                "comments": ["comment3", "comment4", "comment5"]
                //etc etc
            }
            //etc etc
        },
        "allIds": ["task1", "task2", "task3", "task4"]
    },
    "comments": {
        "byId": {
            "comment1": {
                "id": "comment1",
                "comment": "....."
                //etc etc
            },
            "comment2": {
                "id": "comment2",
                "comment": "....."
                //etc etc
            }
            //etc etc
        },
        "allIds": ["comment1", "comment2", "comment3", "comment4", "comment5"]
    }
}
```

I understand the theory and see the benefits of having my state structured like this. In practice though, I'm struggling to map over an array of references in an object and a bit lost of where I should be doing it.

What and where is the most efficient way to map over the references to the item's Ids with the actual items?

Should I be doing this on the parent component mapping over all the references before passing them down as props to child components? Or should I pass the references down to child components as props and then map over them there?

Before switching to redux I was using useContext but with a normalised state. I used the following function to filter what tasks were needed for each taskGroup. [Thanks to ssube who posted this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6)

```
export const filterObject = (objToFilter: any, valuesToFind: string) => {
    return Object.keys(objToFilter)
        .filter((key) => valuesToFind.includes(key))
        .reduce((obj, key) => {
            return {
                ...obj,
                [key]: objToFilter[key],
            };
        }, {});
};
```

Which was then used like so (the same logic was then repeated in my Tasks component to map out comments)

```
{
    Object.values(taskGroupsById)
        .sort((a, b) => a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder)
        .map((taskGroup) => {
            return (
                <TaskGroup
                    key={taskGroup.taskGroupId}
                    taskGroupTitle={taskGroup.taskGroupTitle}
                    tasks={filterObject(
                        tasksById,
                        taskGroupsById[`${taskGroup.taskGroupId}`].tasks
                    )}
                    handleDrawer={handleDrawer}
                    findTaskStatus={findTaskStatus}
                    findAssignedToTask={findAssignedToTask}
                />
            );
        });
}
```

This works ok but I'm not sure if its counter intuitive, as it's beeing calculated in multiple instances of the TaskGroup component instead of just once.

Is there a better method to achieve this? I've tried to create a selector in my slices to recreate this but can't seem to work out how to map over multiple references in an array (as opposed to just one reference as a string).

Any help would be much appreciated even if it is just a nudge in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I be doing this on the parent component mapping over all the references before passing them down as props to child components? Or should I pass the references down to child components as props and then map over them there?

I would recommend the second approach.  This can potentially minimize re-renders and it fits with Redux best practice [Connect More Components to Read Data from the Store](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#connect-more-components-to-read-data-from-the-store).  As explained in the docs:

> Prefer having more UI components subscribed to the Redux store and reading data at a more granular level. This typically leads to better UI performance, as fewer components will need to render when a given piece of state changes.
>
> For example, rather than just connecting a `<UserList>` component and reading the entire array of users, have `<UserList>` retrieve a list of all user IDs, render list items as `<UserListItem userId={userId}>`, and have `<UserListItem>` be connected and extract its own user entry from the store.
>
> This applies for both the React-Redux `connect()` API and the `useSelector()` hook.

---

You have a `taskGroup` object which looks like this:

```
{
  taskGroupId: "taskGroup1",
  tasks: ["task1", "task2"]
...
```

So it is trivial to pass down the array of task ids to your `<TaskGroup>` component:

```
<TaskGroup
  key={taskGroup.taskGroupId}
  taskGroupTitle={taskGroup.taskGroupTitle}
  taskIds={taskGroup.tasks}
...
```

---

Now there are two ways that your `TaskGroup` can handle looking up the task objects.

If you don't need any sorting, then your `TaskGroup` doesn't need to select the task objects.  It can simply iterate through the ids and defer the selecting to a `SingleTask` component, like in the `<UserListItem userId={userId}>` example from the docs.

In your `TaskGroup` component, you will have something like:

```
<ul>
  {taskIds.map(taskId => (
     <SingleTask key={taskId} taskId={taskId} />
  ))}
</ul>
```

Then each `SingleTask` is responsible for accessing its own data.  You can define a selector function, though this one is also simple enough to write inline.

```
const selectTaskById = (state, taskId) => state.tasks.byId[taskId];
```

```
const SingleTask = ({ taskId }) => {

   const task = useSelector(state => state.tasks.byId[taskId]);
   const { description, comments } = task;

   return (
     <li>{description}</li>
   );
}
```

---

If you need to apply sorting or filtering which depends on the properties of the individual task then you will need to select all of the task objects in the `TaskGroup`.  Create a selector that takes your array of ids and returns an array of objects.

Your existing `filterObject` function is not particularly efficient because your state is already so well structured.  You do not need to use any `Array.includes()` statements.  You can simply look up the objects by their keys.

```
const selectTasksByIds = (state, taskIds) => {
  const tasksById = state.tasks.byId;
  return taskIds.map(id => tasksById[id]);
}
```

In your `TaskGroup` component, you will have:

```
const tasks = useSelector(state => selectTasksByIds(state, taskIds));
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply, it has been incredibly helpful. I've definitely been over-complicating things!

Answer (score 2):

As an additional answer: Redux Toolkit includes a `createEntityAdapter` API that is intended to do much of the work of "CRUD"-style updates for normalized data for you automatically, and it also generates selectors for "select one item by ID" and "select the entire set of items as an array":

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-6-performance-normalization#normalizing-data
- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter

Comment: thank you, this sounds great so I will definitely look into this.